# How do i restrict editing on my questions?

Tags: support, editing

I just don't like people messing with my questions on askubuntu, and i don't get all the specifics I need.

Answer (score 10):

As shown in our [help section](https://askubuntu.com/tour):

> Our goal is to have the best answers to every question, so if you see
>   questions or answers that can be improved, you can edit them.
>
> Use edits to fix mistakes, improve formatting, or clarify the meaning
>   of a post.

Basically it is the way this site is (or in general all of the stackexchange sites are) set up.

People can always edit your question. If you do not want people to edit your questions  alot you need to make sure they are clearly written in perfect english, perfectly tagged and having every bit of information it needs for someone to be able to answer it. Probably impossible ;) and even if you do someone still might disagree with your tagging and still edit it.

I would advice to just accept people can edit your questions.